# symfony form entity update

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to create a for with an entity.

My controller:

```
$questionnaire = $em->getRepository('questionnaireBundle:questionnaire')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));

        $form = $this->createForm(new questionnaireType(), $questionnaire);
```

QuestionnaireType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('nom', 'text', array('label' => 'Nom:'));
    $builder->add('nbreQuestions', 'text', array('label' => 'Nombre de questions:'));
    $builder->add('type', 'entity', array('class' => 'questionnaireBundle:type', 'property' => 'type'));
    $builder->add('envoyer', 'submit', array('label' => 'Enregistrer', 'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-success col-md-12')));
}
```

The entity: questionnaire

```
namespace questionnaireBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * questionnaire
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class questionnaire {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nbreQuestions", type="integer")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Veuillez entrer un nombre de questions.")
     * @Assert\Type(type="integer")
     */
    private $nbreQuestions;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     * @return questionnaire
     */
    public function setNom($nom) {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNom() {
        return $this->nom;
    }
    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return type
     */
    public function setType($type) {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getType() {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set nbreQuestions
     *
     * @param integer $nbreQuestions
     * @return questionnaire
     */
    public function setNbreQuestions($nbreQuestions) {
        $this->nbreQuestions = $nbreQuestions;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nbreQuestions
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getNbreQuestions() {
        return $this->nbreQuestions;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return (string) $this->getNom();
    }

}
```

The field nom, nbreQuestions will automatically be fully with the entity questionnaire, but type is not update!

Anybody knows why?

Thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

that must do a second query behind the sense, but you can increase performance by dql & join:

use this code:

```
$questionnaire = $em->createQuery('select q from questionnaireBundle:questionnaire q join q.type t where q.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $id)->getSingleResult();

$form = $this->createForm(new questionnaireType(), $questionnaire);
```

Comment: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 62 near 't where q.id': Error: Class questionnaireBundle\Entity\questionnaire has no association named type

Comment: I no have your entity mapping, I guess that question entity contain type property that is a relation to another entity. Plz add your mapping  here.

Comment: Right! I have added this in my question!

Comment: @anubis why type property is string? and you set that in form as a object?

Comment: I have a select and the user have to choose between 3 strings ("One", "two", "three") for example

Comment: @anubis why type property is string? and you set that in form as a object?, you must change "questionnaire:type" property mapping, assosiation oneToOne to  "type" entity.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of not selecting the proper type in your for is that entity type builds choices as

```
entity_id => property_value
```

So it is comparing your values from questionnaire type to the ids from your type entity and it will not find a match. Moreover if you update your questionnaire object the type will be changed to the id of type entity.

I see here two solutions:

1. proposed by @ghanbari to make relation from questionnaire to type
2. make your form as a service and inject entityManager than build your choices like you want (type => type) and change the field from entity type to choice type